# Storm bolt for Vertica

Tags: apache-storm, vertica

I am new in Storm world and I am looking for good Vertica Bolt which is easy to use and has good performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertica uses JDBC, so you should search for jbdc bolt.

Looks like that there are useful links:

http://jayatiatblogs.blogspot.ru/2012/07/storm-rdbms-integration.html
http://frommyworkshop.blogspot.ru/2012/12/real-time-data-processing-with-storm.html